# QGIS ordered set from layer.getFeatures()

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I need a list of all values of a certain field in a QGIS dataset. To get this, I am using

```
  for festure in layer.getFeatures():
     value=feature[fieldname]
```

This is kind of working, but I have two issues with it, they may have the same solution:

1. I want the data sorted by id, it seems to me that some of the points are not coming in the correct order.
2. It seems rather slow. I have a dataset with a few thousand records and it uses several seconds to go through it.

(the base dataset is a PostGIS table if that matters)

So I have these questions:

1. Is there any way to sort the data returned by getFeatures()?
2. Is there any way to speed up getFeatures()
   or
3. Should/could I use any other way of getting all values from a field?

Comment: look at this post https://nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the article Fran Raga linked to (nyalldawson.net/2016/10/speeding-up-your-pyqgis-scripts ), I did the following:

First:

```
request=QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Id')
iter=layer.getFeatures(request)
for festure in iter:
   value=feature[fieldname]
```

This made the features come sorted in the order I wanted them. According to the article, this should also speed it up, but I did not notice any difference (I did not do any formal tests for speed)

Then I rewrote the featurerequest to only return the field I needed:

```
request =  QgsFeatureRequest().addOrderBy('Id').setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry).setSubsetOfAttributes(['id'], layer.fields() )
```

This speeded it up significantly, that is, from having to wait for a long time to get the results as quickly as I was able to handle it.

I do believe that the most important thing here is the NoGeometry flag, but again, I have not tested that either. The lastest iteration gives me what I need as soon as I need it.

Comment: The first approach worked fine in QGIS 3.24.0.  I didn't try the second